# Getting error that stack.peek() cannot be found. Rest of the program seems to be fine

Tags: java, stack

The main issue seems to be in the removeGreen method. It is supposed to print out the stack without green being listed. I don't know why but when I compile I get an error message saying stack.peek cannot be found. I don't know what is wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Pez
{

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        addPez(stack);

        System.out.println("Stack elements: ");
        printStack(stack);

        removeGreen(stack);

        System.out.println("\n Stack after removing green: ");
        printStack(stack);

        }
        public static void addPez(Stack stack)
        {
        stack.push("yellow");
        stack.push("red");
        stack.push("green");
        stack.push("green");
        stack.push("yellow");
        stack.push("yellow");
        stack.push("red");
        stack.push("green");
        }

        public static void removeGreen(Stack stack)
        {
        Stack tempStack = new Stack();

        while (stack.isEmpty() == false)
        {
        if (stack.peek() != "green")
        {
        tempStack.push(stack.pop());
        } else {
        stack.pop();
        }

        while (tempStack.isEmpty() == false)
        {
        stack.push(tempStack.pop());
        }
}
}

        public static void printStack(Stack stack)
        {
        if (stack.isEmpty())
        return;
        String data = (String) stack.pop();
        System.out.println(data);
        printStack(stack);
        stack.push(data);
        }

}
```

Comment: BTW `!= "green"` is not how you compare Strings in Java

Comment: Compiles for me.

Comment: Me too, though the compiler tells me that there are unsafe / unchecked operations ... 'cos `Stack` is a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the removegreen method is the comparison. You are comparing address of the string that is the reason it is not removing the green element. [How to compare string in java.](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java)

Also you need to fix your loop as the second while loop will run infinite and you will not get any output. you can update the empty check too.

```
public static void removeGreen1(Stack stack) {
    Stack tempStack = new Stack();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        if (!"green".equals(stack.peek())) {
            tempStack.push(stack.pop());
        } else {
            stack.pop();
        }               
    }

    while (!tempStack.isEmpty()) {
        stack.push(tempStack.pop());
    }
}
```